# How to position <footer> below rest of elements

Tags: html, css, position

I have been working on this for way too long, as I cannot seem to figure out how to push the  below the rest of the elements.

I would like IMAGES, INFO, and ADD TO CART to be positioned below all of the other content with the . I cannot believe I am coming to SO with this but I really am stuck. Thanks!

[image]

Here's the live page:

https://fine-grain-2.myshopify.com/products/the-bowden-brown-cherry#

Here is the HTML:

```
<article id="product-details">
    <section class="one columns alpha" id="images">TEST
    </section>
    <section class="one columns" id="info">
        <div>
            <div>
                <h2>{{ product.title | upcase }}</h2>
                {% for variant in product.variants %}
                <h3>{{ variant.title }}</h3>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
            </div>
                <h1>What Sets It Apart?</h1>
            <div>
                <p>This sleeve.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
  </section>
  <section class="one columns omega" id="buy">TEST3</section>

  <footer id="options">
      <a class="four columns alpha images" href="#">
        <span>IMAGES</span>
      </a>
      <a class="four columns info" href="#">
        <span>INFO</span>
      </a>
      <a class="four columns omega buy" href="#">
        <span>ADD TO CART</span>
      </a>
  </footer>

</article><!-- product-details -->
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/*-----Product Page-----*/

#galleria {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#product-details { 
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.galleria-container, .galleria-stage, 
.galleria-images , .galleria-image img , .galleria-image-nav, 
.galleria-image-nav-left, .galleria-image-nav-right, 
.galleria-thumbnails-container, .galleria-info, 
.galleria-tooltip {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.four.columns.images, .four.columns.info {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.four.columns.buy {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

#options {
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 16px;
    position: absolute;
}

#info, #buy {
    visibility: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#product-details section {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(218, 218, 210, 0.5);
}

footer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it already in the bottom?

Comment: In the HTML it is, but its position on the page is not.

Comment: I was saying about the page. I opened the page and saw that the footer thumbnails are staying in the bottom. You mean that or is it something else, or check the site, it is not updated I guess.

Comment: I checked again and they're still above the other content in the <article>. The footer is IMAGES, INFO, and ADD TO CART.

Comment: Oh, the footer thumbnails are not what I'm talking about. It's what I have mentioned above.@PraveenKumar

Comment: Which browser are you using? I am not able to get the same screenshot as what you have posted. I am using Chrome 24!

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'm using chrome 24 as well. Click on the INFO link and you should see the same as in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue that I see if your footer is an absolute position element inside of the article which is set to relative.

The issue is that the content inside your element is set to float left making the article tag not have a height equal to the length of the content.

I did some quick messing around with your CSS and either of these options will get you started:

- Remove the absolute positioning and you'll need to tweak some padding and/or margins.  However, your invisible sections do cause some problems.
- Turn off the floating and displaying inline on this item: .column, .columns.  Then I think you just need to adjust the bottom value of your absolute position.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll work on your first suggestions and see how it goes. I'm in a little over my head with this, but learning a ton.

Comment: Holy crap, just removing the absolute positioning fixed it. Thanks!